# How to detect a keystroke in the Window Procedure method?

Tags: c++, win32gui

I am a bit new to c++ and I am trying to create a gui application to tell me whether my caps lock is active or not. I have already set up the basic UI and it starts up according to plan (by showing me my lock state via colors) but I cannot manage to change the window color at runtime.

here's my code :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
bool state = false;
switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        // All painting occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) != 0) {
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0)));
        }
        else {
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0)));
        }

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    case WM_KEYUP:
    {

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        // All painting occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) != 0) {
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0)));
        }
        else {
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0)));
        }

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;
}

return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

}
```

and thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not the kind of app that inspires the user much, you can only get WM_KEYxxx notifications if the window has the focus.  Use SetTimer().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `(Begin/End)Paint()` in your `WM_KEYUP` handler, and don't call `GetKeyState()` in your `WM_PAINT` handler. Have `WM_KEY(DOWN|UP)` save the desired color to a variable and then call `InvalidateRect()` whenver that variable changes value to trigger a repaint of your window. Let `WM_PAINT` draw the window using the current value of that variable as needed.

Also, your `case` blocks are missing `break` statements.  And you are leaking the `HBRUSH` returned by `CreateSolidBrush()`.

Try something more like this:

```
COLORREF color;

void UpdateColorForCapsLock()
{
    if (GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) {
        color = RGB(0, 255, 0);
    }
    else {
        color = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    }
}

RESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            UpdateColorForCapsLock();
            break;
        }

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(color);
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, hBrush);
            DeleteObject(hBrush);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_KEYUP:
        {
            if (wParam == VK_CAPITAL)
            {
                UpdateColorForCapsLock();
                InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that this only works if I have the user's focus which I can't have if I am typing something in a text input

Comment: To capture keystrokes when your window is not in focus, you would need to use either 1) a `WH_KEYBOARD(_LL)` hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()`, or 2) the `WM_INPUT` message via `RegisterRawInputDevices()`

Answer (score 0):

Capture the `WM_KEYDOWN` message. If i's a Caps Lock key press (check the parameters), make your window repaint itself by calling `InvalidateRect`.